# How to print a string array downwards in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a parameter field which is set to "`one,two,three,four`"
I want it to be printed out like

```
one

two

three

four
```

I have tried splitting it with `Split(numString, ',')`

I can't figure out how to dynamically print out the strings

I want to be able to change how big an array i send to the parameter. So it will work for "`one,two`" and "`one,two,three`"

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to say that I want the crystal report code for a formula field

Answer (score 0):

do this way:

```
Split(numString, ',')[1]&ChrW(13)&Split(numString, ',')
[2]&ChrW(13)&Split(numString, ',')[3]&ChrW(13)&Split(numString, ',')[4]
```